# WGet/Curl failing

Tags: curl, wget

I'm attempting to capture the data at the following url https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web_platform/product_fulfillment_v1?key=9f36aeafbe60771e321a7cc95a78140772ab3e96&is_bot=false&tcin=53180239&store_id=2381&zip=12590&state=NY&latitude=41.640&longitude=-73.830&scheduled_delivery_store_id=1856&required_store_id=2381&has_required_store_id=true&channel=WEB&page=%2Fp%2FA-81640508 When I go to this page directly in a browser I get the information I'm looking for

> {"data":{"product":{"__typename":"Product","tcin":"53180239","notify_me_enabled":false,"fulfillment":{"product_id":"53180239","is_out_of_stock_in_all_store_locations":true,"store_options":[{"location_id":"2381","store":{"location_name":"Paramus","mailing_address":{"address_line1":"900 Bergen Town Ctr","city":"Paramus","state":"New Jersey","postal_code":"07652-5005"}},"search_response_store_type":"PRIMARY","location_available_to_promise_quantity":0.0,"order_pickup":{"availability_status":"UNAVAILABLE"},"in_store_only":{"availability_status":"OUT_OF_STOCK"},"ship_to_store":{"availability_status":"UNAVAILABLE"}}],"shipping_options":{"availability_status":"OUT_OF_STOCK","loyalty_availability_status":"OUT_OF_STOCK","available_to_promise_quantity":0.0,"reason_code":"INVENTORY_UNAVAILABLE","services":[]},"scheduled_delivery":{"availability_status":"UNAVAILABLE","location_available_to_promise_quantity":0.0}}}}}

However, when I try to wget or curl the page, I get an error that the "tcin" variable is null; which it isn't. Could it just be a protection against curl/wget somehow? Basically I want to cron it and then alert me when the item is in stock, but I'm stuck trying to just get the curl/wget to work.

Comment: Both curl and wget work for me on Ubuntu 20.04, and curl on Windows 10 (which doesn't provide wget) -- as long as I quote the URL correctly (which differs by system) since otherwise (on both systems) the & truncates the command causing the error you cite -- plus many others you didn't mention. Did you quote correctly?

Comment: And this is why StackOverflow is beautiful; post that ans an answer and I'll give you the solve!

Comment: This is not programming or development, which is the scope of SO for several years now, plus it arguably falls under 'not reproducible or caused by typo' which is a standard close reason.